# AngularJS ng-repeat and bootstrap to display items in colums from DB

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adapt a template to my MEAN app, and I want to display some info I load from the DB in 3 columns. The problem is, when using ng-repeat, it only displays the data in one column.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div ng-repeat="woman in women">
    <div class= "col-md-4">
        <!--Card-->
          <div class="card">
              <!--Card image-->
              <img class="img-fluid" src="{{woman.image_url}}" alt="{{woman.name}}">
              <!--Card content-->
              <div class="card-body">
                  <!--Title-->
                  <h4 class="card-title">{{woman.name}}</h4>
                  <!--Text-->
                  <p class="card-text"> <h5>{{woman.field}}</h5> <br> {{woman.job}}</p>
                  <a href="#!/women/details/{{woman._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/.Card-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm forcing the images to have the same size, but I would also like to display just part of the pictures in this view, and then in the detailed one, the full image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at this and let me know whether this is what you are looking for,

```
<body ng-app="test">
<div class="row mt-5" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="woman in women">
    <div class= "col-md-4">
        <!--Card-->
          <div class="card flexcss">
              <!--Card image-->
              <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{woman.image_url}}" alt="{{woman.name}}">
              <!--Card content-->
              <div class="card-body">
                  <!--Title-->
                  <h4 class="card-title">{{woman.name}}</h4>
                  <!--Text-->
                  <p class="card-text"> <h5>{{woman.field}}</h5> <br> {{woman.job}}</p>
                  <a href="#!/women/details/{{woman._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/.Card-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.flexcss{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row
}
.card-body{
  padding:5px;
}
```

JS:

```
var app= angular.module('test',[]);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.women= [
      {
      image_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Wonder_Woman_%282017_film%29.jpg',
      name:'wonder women',
      field:'war',
      job:'saviour'
     },
            {
      image_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Wonder_Woman_%282017_film%29.jpg',
      name:'super girl',
      field:'war',
      job:'fighter'
     },
      {
      image_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Wonder_Woman_%282017_film%29.jpg',
      name:'Bat Woman',
      field:'war',
      job:'fighter'
     }
      ]
  }

)
```

https://codepen.io/shankkie/pen/QMmKxz

Comment: Thanks! That is the behaviour I want for my display, but trying with your code is still not working. I saw on your codepen that it is using Bootstrap 3.3.7, but I am using Bootstrap 4. Maybe there is the problem :S Still not working on mine.

Comment: Thank you!! I fixed it :) Well, more or less, since now I can't separate the cards in the rows...

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-src instead of src when displaying images,

```
<img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{woman.image_url}}" alt="{{woman.name}}">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.women = [
  {"_id":"5992b00cf8f760203378872f","name":"Ada Lovelace (Ada Byron)","birthDate":"10 de diciembre de 1815","deceaseDate":"27 de noviembre de 1852","field":"Mathematics","job":"Matemática y escritora, creadora del primer algoritmo para programar una máquina","bio":"Su padre fue el conocido poeta George Byron, y su madre, Anne Isabella Noel Byron, poeta y matemática. (...). Ada Byron se refería a sí misma como una científica poetisa y como analista (y metafísica)","image_url":"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7b/db/e4/7bdbe44fda240b5992b2ce570e273719--kate-winselt-adrienne-bailon.jpg"},
  {"_id":"5992b00cf321360203378872f","name":"Jon right (Ada Byron)","birthDate":"10 de diciembre de 1815","deceaseDate":"27 de noviembre de 1852","field":"Mathematics","job":"Matemática y escritora, creadora del primer algoritmo para programar una máquina","bio":"Su padre fue el conocido poeta George Byron, y su madre, Anne Isabella Noel Byron, poeta y matemática. (...). Ada Byron se refería a sí misma como una científica poetisa y como analista (y metafísica)","image_url":"https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/57e15c417dd0d7d276c7cb7c/master/h_590,c_limit/angelina-jolie-vf-december-2014-ss02.jpg"}
  
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="woman in women">
    <div class= "col-md-4">
        <!--Card-->
          <div class="card">
              <!--Card image-->
              <img class="img-fluid" src="{{woman.image_url}}" alt="{{woman.name}}">
              <!--Card content-->
              <div class="card-body">
                  <!--Title-->
                  <h4 class="card-title">{{woman.name}}</h4>
                  <!--Text-->
                  <p class="card-text"> <h5>{{woman.field}}</h5> <br> {{woman.job}}</p>
                  <a href="#!/women/details/{{woman._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/.Card-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It comes from the DB. This is the schema: name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  birthDate:{
    type: String,
    required: true
    //default: Date.now
  },
  deceaseDate:{
    type: String
    //default: Date.now
  },
  field:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  job:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bio:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image_url:{
    type: String
  }

Comment: I don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: you can console.log($scope.woman) in controller and post it here

Comment: Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ] this is what it shows. each object is a woman with those fields I commented before

Comment: can you put console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.woman)); so that we can see the actual array

Comment: Cannot paste here. Too long. It parses all the info of every woman. My function gets all of them, and refers them as WOMAN because the collection is called WOMEN, and MongoDB can relate with sing-plural.

Comment: just paste at least 1 object of it.

Comment: {"_id":"5992b00cf8f760203378872f","name":"Ada Lovelace (Ada Byron)","birthDate":"10 de diciembre de 1815","deceaseDate":"27 de noviembre de 1852","field":"Mathematics","job":"Matemática y escritora, creadora del primer algoritmo para programar una máquina","bio":"Su padre fue el conocido poeta George Byron, y su madre, Anne Isabella Noel Byron, poeta y matemática. (...). Ada Byron se refería a sí misma como una científica poetisa y como analista (y metafísica)","image_url":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_100_100/p/5/005/0b3/05f/1b61a85.jpg"}

Comment: check the demo above

Comment: It is not a problem of angular, because the controller works propperly. It's a problem of bootstrap, and how to display objects dinamically. It is still not working for me, but thank you :)

Comment: you can contact me via email sajeetharan@outlook.com